# Plosives with trilled release or allophones of /u/?

Tags: phonology, allophones, trills, bilabial

I've been looking at contexts where [ʙ] arises and I stumbled on the [Namuyi wikipedium](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Namuyi_language&oldid=1058162642).  This presents a really interesting phonology, with phonemic /pʙ/, /tʙ/, /bʙ/, and /dʙ/.  Now I don't generally trust wikipedia phonology tables so I went to the sources.  Wikipedia gives two, [Nishida 2013](https://iwate-u.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=13136&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=21) and [Pavlík 2017](https://dspace.cuni.cz/bitstream/handle/20.500.11956/95965/140057444.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y).

Nishida 2013 gives a phonemic analysis, but does not mention bilabial trills at all. Pavlík 2017 does give /p͡ʙ/, /t͡ʙ/, /ʙ ~ b͡ʙ/ and /d͡ʙ/ as phonemic either as an onset before /u/ or as syllabic.

Now for me this very intriguing.  I'm familiar with [ʙ] being an allophone of /u/ after bilabial or even alveolar stops. I've seen it analysed as such in several other Qiangic languages (e.g. Lizu is analysed as such in [Chirkova & Chen 2013](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-international-phonetic-association/article/lizu/01CC130F98CEEED415781F4BE6749005)), so the immediate question is: "What separates Namuyi from other superficially similar Qiangic languages?  Why is it phonemic?"  It's certainly not implausible that it could have been elevated to the level of a phoneme, however you need evidence.  So I read on and I find the paper references two earlier analyses of Huáng 1992 and Yǐn 2016.  Pavlík 2017 states that both of them analyze [ʙ] as an allophone of /u/ in the expected positions.  Huáng 1992 even analyses speakers from the same village as Pavlík 2017.  However to my knowledge the paper nowhere refutes this claim or justifies their choice to analyze these trills as phonemic.  No minimal pairs or near minimal pairs are provided.

So I'm left with my questions.  [ʙ] as an allophone of /u/ seems to me to be the overwhelmingly more natural way to analyze data presented. What reasons could there be to analyze it this way lacking any minimal pairs?

---

References:

- Chirkova, Katia; Chen, Yiya (2013), *"Lizu"*, *Journal of the International Phonetic Association*.
- 黃布凡 [*Huáng, Bùfán*], ed. (1992), 藏緬語族語言詞彙 [*Tibeto-Burman language vocabulary*] (in Chinese), Beijing: Minzu University Press.
- Nishida, Fuminobu (2013). *"Phonetics and Phonology of Dzolo Dialect of Namuyi"*.
- Pavlík, Štěpán (2017). *"The Description of Namuzi Language"*. Charles University.
- 尹蔚彬 [*Yǐn, Wèibīn*] (2016), 納木茲語語法標註文本 [*Grammar of Namuzi with Annotated Texts*] (in Chinese), Beijing: 社會科學文獻出版社 [*Social Science Literature Press*].